# Double subject construction?

Tags: grammar, particle-が, subjects

I've recently been having trouble with constructions that seem to mark two subjects in the same clause. I've only encountered them in ～の方が... constructions, but I can't seem to make sense of them grammatically. Here are some examples:

> 1. 当然、都心より郊外のほう**が**家賃**が**安い。 (from a vocabulary book)
> 2. （人）よりも自分の方**が**知識**が**あると思う (from アルク)

My questions are: why are two subjects allowed here, and are there other constructions in which this happens?  So far my thoughts on this are:

(a) 方 seems to be a subject, but not have a verb. So maybe this is simply be some kind of relative-clause-like construction with the noun elided away, e.g. 家賃が安い[ところだ] and 知識がある[人だ]. But this seems a little odd - I don't know of anywhere else where this is possible.

(b) The second sentence might bracket as （人）よりも自分の方が([blah]と思う), rather than (（人）よりも自分の方が[blah])と思う. This makes perfect sense, but I suspect that the と思う could be removed to leave a valid sentence, so this explanation seems a little spurious. In any case this doesn't explain the first sentence.

So I'm a little confused. Any light anyone can shed on this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Ack, my formatting messed up. I don't really know how to fix that, because it looks fine on the edit screen...

Comment: I edited it.  You have to use HTML tags to format kana.  It shows fine while you're editing, but it doesn't work correctly for some reason.

Comment: @istrasci Oh, I didn't know HTML was allowed here. Thanks.

Comment: It's limited.  There should be a help button when editing that shows what you can use.

Comment: It’s called “_topic-comment_” or “_double subject_,” and found in Japanese, Korean, Malay, and Indonesian.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @Flaw flawlessly explains, Japanese sentences can have clausal predicates. This is what causes what is commonly known as double-subject constructions, although I believe "clausal predicates" really illustrates the structure better.

I assume you have heard constructions like

> 彼は髪が長い  He has long hair

Some teachers/textbooks might explain this away by saying that 彼 is a topic, not a subject, but that creates problems when you run into sentences like

> 彼が髪が長いんだ！ He is the one with long hair!

Here the first が is an exhaustive-listing が. When multiple がs occur in a main clause, the first is usually exhaustive-listing. Note that 髪が長いのは彼だ might be more common, but I don't consider the above ungrammatical. Also, dependent/relative clauses cannot have topics, so you might see

> 彼が髪が長い理由は ... だ  The reason for his long hair is ...

although I think in this case 彼の髪が長い理由は...だ might also be as/more common.

In your example sentence, のほう needs to have a が (This would also fall under the exhaustive-listing category) to have the comparative meaning

> 郊外のほうが家賃が安い  Rent is **cheaper** in the suburbs

Changing the が to a は would lose the comparative meaning

> 郊外のほうは家賃が安い  Rent is cheap in the suburbs

As a side note, I'm not exactly sure what the function of のほう would be in this case, I think you can see it either as a filler, or as something that directs your attention to 郊外. 郊外は家賃が安い would mean almost the same.

To address Billy's question in his comment

> 郊外が家賃が安い It is in the suburbs that rent is cheap

is grammatical, but quite narrow in meaning. And again, 家賃が安いのは郊外だ is probably more common to convey this meaning.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean by "exclusive-listing", please? (I could perhaps reverse-engineer a definition from your XのはY sentences, but I'm wondering what it means in general, without reference to this double-が nonsense.)

Comment: Oh - perhaps the name is more transparent than it seemed at first glance. The "exclusive-listing" meaning of が is the one that renders "YがX" as meaning "the (only) thing with property X (in the world / in consideration / in the scope of this discussion) is Y", is that right?

Comment: @Billy I think (but don't know) dainichi might have meant "exhaustive-listing", as described here: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/22/whats-the-difference-between-wa-%E3%81%AF-and-ga-%E3%81%8C/51#51

Answer (score 11):

I think this is how:

Consider first Clause<sub>1</sub>: 家賃が安い. 
The structure is Subject<sub>1</sub>+が+Predicate<sub>1</sub>. 
Subject<sub>1</sub>: 家賃 
Predicate<sub>1</sub>: 安い

Now consider Clause<sub>2</sub>: (都心より)郊外のほうが家賃が安い. 
The structure is Subject<sub>2</sub>+が+Predicate<sub>2</sub>, where Predicate<sub>2</sub> is Clause<sub>1</sub>.
Subject<sub>2</sub>: 郊外のほう 
Predicate<sub>2</sub>: 家賃が安い

---

Predicate: The part of a sentence or clause saying something about the subject

Comment: So can I say 郊外が家賃が安い? (That is, can I change the subject?)